# Ionic - avoid white keyboard background when it is showing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app with a colored background and every time the keyboard shows it first put a white background on the space it will occupy. I have made a video (iOS) from a new blank app to illustrate. Here is the simple code I have added.

`<ion-content padding style="background-color: green;">
 <ion-textarea style="background-color: yellow;"></ion-textarea>
</ion-content>`

Is there a way to always have the green background color?

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C30Y9I52tB2kq0yh3Ip3kBIZERRF-vo0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No :(. Please let me know if you do!